# "Raw" offsets to "disassembler" offsets?

Tags: hex, offset

This is a very silly question, but surprisingly I've had a problem with this today.
In a hex editor, I've found an offset and I wanted to take a look at that code in a disassembler. In the hex-editor, the offset is EBE75, and it looks like this:

[image]

Obviously a CALL, I wanted to find it in IDA/Olly and take a look. This is, however, where I wasn't sure how to translate that to an offset that IDA/Olly could understand. Do I add the imagebase, or maybe the offset of the .text section? I've managed to find the code using IDA's hexscan, and it's located at address `004ECA75`:

[image]

The difference between these addresses is `4ECA75 - EBE75 = 400C00`. This is quite surprising to me, where did that number come from? How is this related to the .exe's layout?

Comment: Your "raw offsets" are also called "file offsets"; this might help you find relevant commands.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To convert a raw offset in a PE file to its corresponding "disassembler offset" (known as the virtual address or VA), you need to perform the following steps:

**Step 1**

Using a PE editor, look at the PE file's section table to find the section containing the file offset.

For example, let's say your PE file's section table looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Name  | Virtual Address | Virtual Size | Raw Offset | Raw Size |
|--------+-----------------+--------------+------------+----------|
| .text  |    00001000     |   00152CA1   |  00000400  | 00152E00 |
| .data  |    00154000     |   000040C0   |  00153200  | 00004200 |
| .rsrc  |    00159000     |   00062798   |  00157400  | 00062800 |
| .reloc |    001BC000     |   00003B3C   |  001B9C00  | 00003C00 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see above that the section containing raw offset `EBE75` is the `.text` section, since `00000400 <= EBE75 < 00153200`.

**Step 2**

Using a PE editor, look up the PE file's image base. For example, let's say your file's image base is `00400000`.

**Step 3**

Perform the following calculation:

```
(target raw offset) - (raw offset of section) + (virtual address of section) + (image base)
= (target virtual address)
```

Filling in the example values above, we find that the virtual address for raw offset `EBE75` is:

```
EBE75 - 00000400 + 00001000 + 00400000
= 4ECA75
```

Comment: Nice explanation, it's perfectly clear now, thanks :)

Comment: `00000400 <= EBE75 < 00053200` umm, no... Rest of answer is nice, though.

Comment: @FRob Oops, yeah, good point. Doesn't change much though.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @FRob! I've fixed the example section table above.

Answer (score 2):

**ollydbg 1.10**

if you have

1. the binary loaded in ollydbg
2. disasm window is in the correct module
3. the binary is also open in hexeditor

   **Right Click -> View -> Executable File**

In the New Window do `ctrl+g` and enter the offset you saw in hexeditor `ebe75`

```
right click in new window -> follow in disassembler
```

in hexeditor 0x1529 has the 0xe8 opcode

```
xxd -s 0x1520 -l 0x10 -g 1 c:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe
0001520: ff d6 6a 01 a3 4c 4d 01 01 e8 e9 f8 ff ff 6a 69  ..j..LM.......ji
```

**in ollydbg after rightclick-> view -> executable file and ctrl+g 1520 in new window**

```
00001520    FFD6            CALL    NEAR ESI
00001522    6A 01           PUSH    1
00001524    A3 4C4D0101     MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[1014D4C], EAX
00001529    E8 E9F8FFFF     CALL    00000E17
0000152E    6A 69           PUSH    69
```

**in new window rightclick -> view image in disassembler**

```
01002120  |.  FFD6                   CALL    NEAR ESI                         ; \GetProfileIntW
01002122  |.  6A 01                  PUSH    1                                ; /Arg1 = 00000001
01002124  |.  A3 4C4D0101            MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[gbUseSep], EAX     ; |
01002129  |.  E8 E9F8FFFF            CALL    InitSciCalc                      ; \InitSciCalc
0100212E  |.  6A 69                  PUSH    69                               ; /TableName = 69
```