# IDA - How to transform VA to FO?

Tags: ida, offset, address

I'm using IDA Pro to disassemble/modify a PE file. How can I get the file offset in the '.exe' where a specific data/instruction resides. Or how can I get the file offset which is the source of a virtual address?

Comment: See http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8050/raw-offsets-to-disassembler-offsets

Comment: Can you give me some more practical advice? I know the theory but for god sake - I can't always do this complex calculations!

Answer (score 9):

At the bottom left of the IDA View, you'll see the location of the cursor, as file offset (red) as well as virtual location (blue).

(Underlines by me, not by Ida).

[image]

Comment: Do you also know how can I copy it into clipboard?

Comment: What if it [gives me this](https://i.imgur.com/X8sNkht.png)?

Answer (score 3):

To find it using IDAPython:

```
ida_loader.get_fileregion_offset(ea)
```

where "ea" is your virtual offset like `0x400000`.

Comment: For anyone interested, there is a reverse function, too: `get_fileregion_ea(offset)`, where offset is a long. More info about the two functions here: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_loader-module.html#get_fileregion_ea