# Differences between hex-editor and Ghidra and how to find strings

Tags: ghidra, hex

I just started playing around with reverse engineering and Ghidra, so please bear with me.

I wanted to run an old game. One [version](https://archive.org/details/lz-2_20220119) available on archive.org does not work even when I have mounted the ISO, the [other one](https://archive.org/details/Loewe2) does. As a learning exercise, I wanted to try patching the latter anyway: https://archive.org/download/Loewe2/Loewe2.iso/Setup%2FWinRoot%2FTerzio%2FLoewenzahn%202%2FLoewenzahn%202.exe

When I run the exe without the ISO mounted I get the error message **Bitte die CD-ROM "Löwenzahn 2" einlegen!**, which means **Please insert CD-ROM "Löwenzahn 2"!**.

So I ran `strings -t x Loewenzahn\ 2.exe | grep einlegen` and got the output `17020  einlegen!`. I found the same address using the hex-editor Okteta.

`file Loewenzahn\ 2.exe` gives the following output:

```
Loewenzahn 2.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Now when I import Loewenzahn 2.exe into Ghidra and run all analyzers, there's a discrepancy between the addresses and I can't find the string "einlegen" via Search > For Strings....

Ghidra:

[image]

Okteta:

[image]

Why is there an offset and can I configure Ghidra to start at 0? Can I configure Ghidra to show the raw strings, like "Th is program canno t be run in DOS mode"? And how can I find it using the String search?

Comment: Looks like I need to calculate the virtual address to find the corresponding section in the disassembled code: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8050/raw-offsets-to-disassembler-offsets

Comment: When I use Ghidra's Hex editor via Window > Bytes, it only shows the contents of the file up to the PADDINGXX section. However, Okteta shows more data after that point, which is where the string "einlegen" is defined as well.

Comment: I'm is possible to append data to an Windows executable which can be used by the executable. But on a strict perspective this data does not belong to the executable as it was just appended. A common example for such executables are self-extracting archives and installers. May be Ghidra only shows you the actual executable content? As the executable seems to be an installer I would check if a program like 7Zip can extract it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This exe is not an installer and I couldn't extract it either. However, I tried Cutter with the Ghidra plugin and it listed all the strings and recognized library functions out of the box.